# Histogram of lists enteries

Tags: python, list

I have a number of lists as follows:

```
list1 = ['a_1','a_2','b_17','c_19']
list2 = ['aa_1','a_12','b_15','d_39']
list3 = ['a_1','a_200','ba_1','u_0']
```

I wish to generate a histogram based on the labels, ignoring the numbering, that is, `a` has 4 entries over all the lists, `ba` 1 entry, `u` has 1 entry, and so on. The labels, are file names from a specific folder, before adding the numbers, so it is a finite known list.

How can I perform such a count without a bunch of ugly loops? Can I use `unique` here, somehow?

Comment: You can combine the lists into one, do a loop to remove the numbers, then start counting with a dictionary.  It's only two loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot acheive it without a loop. But you can instead use list comphrension to make it into a single line. Something like this.

```py
list1 = ['a_1','a_2','b_17','c_19']
list2 = ['aa_1','a_12','b_15','d_39']
list3 = ['a_1','a_200','ba_1','u_0']

lst = [x.split('_')[0] for x in (list1 + list2 + list3)]

print({x: lst.count(x) for x in lst})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) initialized to `0` to count the occurrence and get a nice container with the required information.

---

So, define the container:

```
from collections import defaultdict
histo = defaultdict(int)
```

I'd like to split the operation into methods.

First get the prefix from the string, to be used as key in the dictionary:

```
def get_prefix(string):
    return string.split('_')[0]
```

This works like

```
get_prefix('az_1')
#=> 'az'
```

Then a method to update de dictionary:

```
def count_elements(lst):
    for e in lst:
        histo[get_prefix(e)] += 1
```

---

Finally you can call this way:

```
count_elements(list1)
count_elements(list2)
count_elements(list3)

dict(histo)
#=> {'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'aa': 1, 'd': 1, 'ba': 1, 'u': 1}
```

Or directly

```
count_elements(list1 + list2 + list3)
```

---

**To get the unique count, call it using `set`:**

```
count_elements(set(list1 + list2 + list3))
dict(histo)
{'ba': 1, 'a': 4, 'aa': 1, 'b': 2, 'u': 1, 'd': 1, 'c': 1}
```